# auto populate common columns of all tables using triggers

Tags: oracle, trigger

I have the following 4 tables:

- course
- section
- student
- enrollment

All of them have 4 columns in common that I want to auto-populate before an insert or update.

At first the simple `insert trigger` was giving me an *infinite recursion* error.

After researching for a while I found out that using views and an `instead of` trigger could be a better solution. Now when I insert a row with `course_no`, `description`, `cost` and `prerequisite` it gives an error that `CREATED_BY` can't be null. However, the values should have been automatically inserted by the trigger.

I've been working on it for a few hours now, but had no luck.

The course table is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE COURSE 
(
COURSE_NO NUMBER(8, 0) NOT NULL 
, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, COST NUMBER(9, 2) 
, PREREQUISITE NUMBER(8, 0) 
, CREATED_BY VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, CREATED_DATE DATE NOT NULL 
, MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, MODIFIED_DATE DATE NOT NULL 
)
```

The view for course is defined as

```
CREATE VIEW v_course 
AS SELECT CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_DATE
FROM COURSE
```

The instead of trigger is as follows

```
create or replace TRIGGER course_trRg INSTEAD OF
INSERT ON v_course
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO course (
    created_by,
    created_date,
    modified_by,
    modified_date
) VALUES (
    user,
    sysdate,
    user,
    sysdate
);
END;
```

This is how I'm trying to insert

```
INSERT INTO v_course (
course_no,
description,
cost,
prerequisite
) VALUES (
1231,
'desc',
1,
1
);
```

All the tables have the columns `created_by`, `created_date`, `modified_by`, `modified_date` in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post what you tried for a simple row level trigger so it isn't obvious how you got an infinite recursion error.  My assumption is that you tried to insert into the table in your trigger rather than simply setting the column values.  Creating a view and an instead of trigger is vastly overcomplicating the problem.

My assumption is that you want something like this.  I'm not clear why `modified_by` and `modified_date` are `not null` since there is logically no modification date or user if a row has just been inserted.  If you want to populate `modified_by` and `modified_date` on the initial insert, you can add that to the `inserting` branch.

```
create or replace trigger course_trg
  before insert or update on course
  for each row
declare
begin
  if( inserting )
  then
    :new.created_by := user;
    :new.created_date := sysdate;
  elsif( updating )
  then
    :new.modified_by := user;
    :new.modified_date := sysdate;
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: `modified_by` is `NOT NULL`.  You need to put the assignments of the `modified_*` columns outside if the `IF .. END IF;` block

Comment: @MichaelKutz - That's why I made the comment that it wasn't obvious to me why those columns were `NOT NULL` since it doesn't generally make sense to have a `modified_date` on a column that has never been modified.